# Meteor pages blank for logged users on some systems

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor app which works fine on my older MacBookPro (10.6.8 Snow Leopard) and also runs on a newer MacBook (10.10.5) but some of the pages don't show when I login. The same is true of my other friend who works on a similar MacBook. We get the browser warning:

`Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() in an onBeforeAction?`

Here is a live and perfectly functional version of the app: http://sscprobs.meteor.com/

`layout.js` shows at all times with header, login buttons, etc.

When user is not logged in, the home route, for example, shows intro text as normal, but that text disappears upon login. It seems to me the trouble must lie with the accounts system and/or routing. Logging in with either Google or Twitter reproduces the problem equally (Facebook login is not configured for now).

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot. Here is my `router.js`:

```
Router.route('/', function() {
    this.render('home');
});

Router.route('/user/:_username', {
  name: 'user_profile',
  data: function() { return Meteor.user();} 
});

Router.route('/create', function() {
  this.render('createEvent');
}, {
  name: 'create'
});

Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
  if (!Meteor.userId()) {
    // if the user is not logged in, render the Login template
    this.render('home');
  } else {
    // otherwise don't hold up the rest of hooks or our route/action function
    // from running
    this.next();
  }
}, {
  only: ['create']
});

Router.route('/insert', function() {
  this.render('insertEvent');
});

Router.route('/events/:slug', {
  name: 'event',
  data: function() { return Events.findOne({slug: this.params.slug});}
});



Router.route('/useremail', function() {
    this.render('userEmail');
}, {
    name: 'userEmail'
});


Router._filters = {
  hasCompletedProfile: function() {
    if(!this.ready()) return;
    var user = Meteor.user();
    if (user && ! userProfileComplete(user)){
      this.render('userEmail');
    } else {
      this.next();
    } 
  }, 
}; 

// copied from Telesc.pe router.js
filters = Router._filters;
Router.onBeforeAction(filters.hasCompletedProfile);


Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
});
```

Here my package list:

```
accounts-facebook          1.0.4  Login service for Facebook accounts
accounts-google            1.0.4  Login service for Google accounts
accounts-twitter           1.0.4  Login service for Twitter accounts
aldeed:autoform            5.5.0  Easily create forms with automatic insert a...
aldeed:collection2         2.5.0  Automatic validation of insert and update o...
autopublish                1.0.3  Publish the entire database to all clients
blaze                      2.1.2  Meteor Reactive Templating library
cmather:handlebars-server  2.0.0  Allows handlebars templates to be defined o...
email                      1.0.6  Send email messages
insecure                   1.0.3  Allow all database writes by default
iron:router                1.0.9  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
meteor-platform            1.2.2  Include a standard set of Meteor packages i...
mquandalle:jade            0.4.3_1  Jade template language
msavin:mongol              1.1.5  The insanely handy development package for ...
percolate:synced-cron      1.2.1  Allows you to define and run scheduled jobs...
service-configuration      1.0.4  Manage the configuration for third-party se...
stevezhu:fbgraph           1.2.0* Node.js module to access the Facebook graph...
todda00:friendly-slugs     0.3.4  Generate URL friendly slugs from a field wi...
twbs:bootstrap             3.3.5  The most popular front-end framework for de...
useraccounts:bootstrap     1.12.3  Accounts Templates styled for Twitter Boot...
useraccounts:iron-routing  1.12.3  UserAccounts package providing routes conf...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Yes, I want to add more information to give a minimal example, but I'm not sure where to start short of supplying every other file. I'll add some more, but any more pointers on this most welcome.